# Why strrev() php function doesn't work in a while?

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm testing some php features on string but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
$string = "L'eau est claire.";   
$string2 = explode(' ', $string);  

$count = count($string) - 1;  
while ($i <= $count)  
{   
  strrev($string2[$i]);  
  $i++;  
}

$string3 = implode (' ', $string2);  
echo $string3;
```

I tried the function `strrev` out the while and it does work.
Can you give me a clue?
Thanks a lot.
Sorry for the English, I'm French.

Comment: What results do you get? What do you expect to see?

Comment: You should consider using of `foreach` loop instead of `while`. The code is much clearer: http://ideone.com/AQgfJ

Answer (score 4):

The function [`strrev`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) doesn't modify the string in place - it returns a new string. In your code you aren't using the result of `strrev` - you are calling the function and then discarding the result. You need an assignment here:

```
$string2[$i] = strrev($string2[$i]);
```